# I am trying to perform unit testing in my code using jest but getting error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I tried to perform unit testing in my code that will take two parameters in the function and then test whether the function works or not. I am new to jest and still trying to figure out how to write the test cases.

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface AlertProps {
  message: string;
  onClose: () => void
}

const Button = styled.button`
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    margin: 1em;
    border: 3px;
    padding: 0.25em 6em;
`;

const Para = styled.p`
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  
`;

const Box = styled.div`
  background-color: #b81c36;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10px
 
`;
 
const Alert: FC<AlertProps> = ({ message, onClose }) => {
  return(
    <>
        <Box>
          <Para >{message}</Para>
          <Button  onClick={onClose}>Close</Button>
        </Box>
    </>
  );
}

export default Alert;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Test Utilities](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#test-utilities) of `styled-components` and [enzyme](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/).

E.g.

`Alert.tsx`:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface AlertProps {
  message: string;
  onClose: () => void;
}

export const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 3px;
  padding: 0.25em 6em;
`;

export const Para = styled.p`
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
`;

export const Box = styled.div`
  background-color: #b81c36;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
`;

const Alert: FC<AlertProps> = ({ message, onClose }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Box>
        <Para>{message}</Para>
        <Button onClick={onClose}>Close</Button>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default Alert;
```

`Alert.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Alert, { Box, Button, Para } from './Alert';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { enzymeFind } from 'styled-components/test-utils';

describe('65697242', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mOnClose = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(<Alert message="teresa teng" onClose={mOnClose}></Alert>);
    const button = enzymeFind(wrapper, Button);
    button.simulate('click');
    const para = enzymeFind(wrapper, Para);
    expect(enzymeFind(wrapper, Box)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(para.text()).toBe('teresa teng');
    expect(mOnClose).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65697242/Alert.test.tsx (5.402 s)
  65697242
    ✓ should pass (42 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 Alert.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.86 s
```

Comment: I followed the code but I get while importing styled-component-test-utils. Coulld you please tell what other files I need to install to ignore the error/